# Django: Adding an instance of object to all ForeignKey related models

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, django-forms

I have model **Chamber**:

```
class Chamber(models.Model):
    chamber_name    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And related model **ChamberProperty**:

```
class ChamberProperty(models.Model):
    chamber         = models.ForeignKey(Chamber, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    property_name   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    property_value  = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
```

Right now a **Chamber** can have many **ChamberProperty**. The requirements were just changed to make it so that if a **ChamberProperty** is added to a **Chamber**, it gets added to all future **Chamber** instances as well, with an empty **property_value (default=None)**, so that the next time the form for creating a new **Chamber** instance is loaded, all previous **ChamberProperty.property_name** are loaded in the form, and empty.

Example forms:

First time a Chamber instance is created:

```
Chamber.chamber_name: Foo
ChamberProperty.property_name: Bar
ChamberProperty.property_value: Baz
```

Second time a Chamber instance is created:

```
Chamber.chamber_name: Qux
ChamberProperty.property_name: Bar # Old property, retain the name
ChamberProperty.property_value: None # Old property, value empty
ChamberProperty.property_name: Quux # New property, added by a button
ChamberProperty.property_value: 700 # New property, value filled with input box
```

Third time a Chamber instance is created:

```
Chamber.chamber_name: Corge
ChamberProperty.property_name: Bar # Old property, retain the name
ChamberProperty.property_value: None # Old property, value empty
ChamberProperty.property_name: Quux # Old property, retain the name
ChamberProperty.property_value: None # Old property, value empty
ChamberProperty.property_name: Ouier # New property, added by a button
ChamberProperty.property_value: Grault # New property, value filled with input box
```

So on and so forth.

For clarification: If you create Chamber A, with "**ChamberProperty** Temperature", then the next time you create a **Chamber**, Chamber B, it will already have "**ChamberProperty** Temperature". You can then add a new **ChamberProperty** to Chamber B, say, "Degrees" with whatever value. Then if you create a new **Chamber**, Chamber C, it will already have "**ChamberProperty** Temperature AND Degrees".

Now I realise that I would then have to add **ChamberProperty** instances recursively to all other **Chamber** instances.

New properties and values are added in the form with a jQuery script, I have that already, as such:

```
<div class="card loading-card" id="card-loaded">
    <h3 class="card-header bg-primary text-white">
        Add Chamber
    </h3>
    <div class="card-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ properties_formset.management_form }}
        <!-----------Chamber------------>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align:top">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                {% for field in chamber_form %}
                                    <td>{{ field|as_crispy_field }}</td>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <br />
                    <!-----------Chamber Properties------------>
                    <td><p>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp</p></td>
                    <td>
                        <table class="new-chamber-properties" id="propertiestable">
                        <script type="text/html" id="property-template">
                            <div id="property-__prefix__">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        {% for field in properties_formset.empty_form %}
                                            <td>{{ field|as_crispy_field }}</td>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </script>

                        <div id="property-form">
                            <tr>
                                {% for properties_form in properties_formset %}
                                    <div id="property-{{ forloop.counter0 }}"></div>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tr>
                        </div>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#" id="add-property-button" class="btn btn-outline-primary add-item">Add Properties</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#" id="remove-property-button" class="btn btn-outline-danger remove-item">Remove Properties</a>
                            </td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.add-item').click(function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var count = $('#property-form').children().length;
            console.log(count)
            var tmplMarkup = $('#property-template').html();
            var compiledTmpl = tmplMarkup.replace(/__prefix__/g, count);
            $('div#property-form').append(compiledTmpl);

            // update form count
            $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').attr('value', count + 1);

            // some animate to scroll to view our new form
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#add-property-button").position().top - 200 }, 800);
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            var tmplMarkup = $('#property-template').html();
            var compiledTmpl = tmplMarkup.replace(/__prefix__/g, i);
            $('div#property-form').append(compiledTmpl);
            // update form count
            $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').attr('value', i + 1);
        }
        document.getElementById("id_form-0-property_name").value = "Process";
        document.getElementById("id_form-1-property_name").value = "Type";
        document.getElementById("id_form-2-property_name").value = "Model";
        document.getElementById("id_form-3-property_name").value = "Electrode Diameter";
        document.getElementById("card-loaded").style.visibility = "visible";

        $('.remove-item').click(function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var count = $('#property-form').children().length;
            console.log(count);
            if (count > 0) {
                var successCount = count - 1;
                console.log(successCount);
                var formlist = $('#property-form')[0];
                while (count > successCount) {
                    var childNode = formlist.lastChild;
                    formlist.removeChild(childNode);
                    count = $('#property-form').children().length;
                }
                // update form count
                $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').attr('value', count);

                // some animate to scroll to view our new form
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#remove-property-button").position().top - 200 }, 800);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm not sure how to even go about doing this.

I was thinking perhaps something like, when the form loads, retrieve all **ChamberProperty** instances for that customer, but then if I set those values to nothing, it would change the values on all the other **Chamber** instances as well.

Any help with this?

Comment: "... if a ChamberProperty is added to a Chamber, it gets added to all future Chamber instances as well". Do you mean a _new ChamberProperty instance_, or an instance with _a new name_ that hasn't been there yet?

Comment: It would be a new instance of **ChamberProperty**, related to the **Chamber** being created, but with all previous **ChamberProperty.property_name** pre-filled in, and empty values.

Comment: You can also look at using a JSONField for the properties which can have keys added/removed without migrating the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you current model doesn't reflect your requirements. What constitutes a *property*? Obviously it's only the name, and not its value. The value should be kept in a separate model instead that's associated with a name and a chamber:

```
class ChamberProperty(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ChamberPropertyValue(models.Model):
    chamber = models.ForeignKey(Chamber, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    property = models.ForeignKey(ChamberProperty, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
```

When a new chamber is created, you will immediately add one `ChamberPropertyValue` for every `ChamberProperty` that's present in the database. This way old chambers will keep their state **not** having any newer names / properties associated with them. This code snippet should go in your form's validation after creating a new `chamber`:

```
for prop in ChamberProperty.objects.all():
    ChamberPropertyValue.objects.get_or_create(property=prop, chamber=chamber)
```